# QScrollArea - how to do precise programmatic scrolling

Tags: qt

I am using Qt to build a view for multipage documents.  I'm drawing each page to a separate QLabel widget, like in the ImageViewer example app.

The QLabels are organized vertically using QVBoxLayout.  This all works nicely, with a little grey margin between the pages.

What I want now is, when the user does page down, to move the scroll so that the top of a particular QLabel appears right at the top of the window.  the "ensure" functions might do that, but I'm not immediately seeing how.

Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: Did you try `QScrollArea::ensureWidgetVisible`?

Comment: Yes, but each of my widgets is taller than the viewport.  What happens is I wind up looking at the middle of the page.

Answer (score 3):

If a child widget is taller that the viewport height `ensureWidgetVisible` scrolls to the middle of the widget.

If you need to scroll to the top of the widget you can do it easily with a little calculation:

```
//childWidget - QLabel you want to move to
//area - QScrollArea

// calculate childWidget position in coordinates of the viewport
const QPoint p = childWidget->mapTo(area, QPoint(0,0));

// move scroll bar
area->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(p.y() + area->verticalScrollBar()->value());
```

Comment: This didn't work exactly for me, but it led me to a related approach which did work, so thank you.  I wound up with this:
     QRect r = childWidget.geometry();
     area->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(r.top());

Comment: Fixed a little bug in the code. My solution is more general: it will work for nested widgets. You approach is correct for your case but it works for the first level widgets only.